# Find tags in sentence, exclude them, and then put them back in the same order and place

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say that I have some string like this:

```
string str = "This is an <b>Example</b> of the string"
```

I need to take `<b>` and `</b>` out of the string and make it look like this, so I can use it like that for needs other then printing:

```
string edtStr = "This is an Example of the string."
```

But afterwards, I want the tags back in so I could print that section with bold attribute. What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: Just parse the string, save the indexes where the tags are and remove them. After that simply insert them again.

Comment: the value on the string will remain the same as it was when you removed them?

Comment: Yes, it will remain the same.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the HTML using html parser.Here is little program using HTML Agility Pack. What is doing the trick is `node.RemoveChild(oldChild, keepGrandChild)`. You can extend the logic with adding all the tags which you remove like `<b>, <i>` and so on.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string html = "<span>This is an <b>Example</b> of the string</span>";

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        List<HtmlNode> spanNodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "span").ToList();

        foreach (HtmlNode node in spanNodes)
        {
            HtmlNode boldNode = node.SelectSingleNode("b");
            node.RemoveChild(boldNode, true);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
    }
```

For this to work you need to install with NuGet

```
PM> Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```

And add `using HtmlAgilityPack;`

Comment: Won't `RemoveChild` remove whatever is inside `<b>` also?

Comment: Because of that we have the property keepGrandChild to true. This will prevent deliting the content in the <b> tag.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then. That's why I use named properties all the time. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, mate. This helped. :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a new string without the html tag while the existing string remains as it is. You can use both for different purposes.

Strings are immutable in C#.

Comment: And how he will create it, if the string comes from external source like html page and he wants to strip up the bold tags ?

Comment: @mybirthname: strings are immutable in C# regardless of where you get them from.

Comment: So what if they are immutable, I don't get this point ... The op ask how to create it, the answer is create a new string. Everybody knows that he need to create new string or overwrite the previous one. This is not the problem of the op. The problem is how strings which contains <b></b> in them, to be strip out of the <b></b> tags.